# Linear Programming: Absolute Value in the Objective Function

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am trying to reformulate a linear programming problem with an absolute value in the objective function. I decided to use a proxy method mentioned in the 'Absolute values in the objective function' section of [this article](https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/Optimization_with_absolute_values).

I didn't get why 'if the objective is a minimization problem of the form $-|f(x)| + g(y)$ or is a maximization problem of the form $|f(x)| + g(y)$, unfortunately, the model cannot be reformulated as a standard LP model'.

For example, if we look at a maximization problem of the form $|f(x)| + g(y)$, can we not reformulate this as:

$\max U + g(y)$

s.t. $U \le |f(x)|$, i.e. $U\le f(x)$ and $U\le-f(x)$

I don't see why this formulation wouldn't work?

Comment: did I answer the question?

Comment: Yes you did! Sorry, I'm new and not able to up vote your answer. Thank you!

Comment: Good to hear! You should be able to mark the question as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work for maximizing $|f(x)|+g(y)$ because $U \leq f(x)$ and $U \leq -f(x)$ together with the objective of maximizing $U$ means that at optimality $U = \min\{f(x), -f(x)\} = -|f(x)|$. So you are maximizing $-|f(x)|+g(y)$ instead of $|f(x)|+g(y)$.